# Excel 2007 getting statistics in column b based on values in first column a

Tags: excel-2007

If there is already an answer please redirect me.

I want to get statistics from measurements of my drill holes.

Column A holds the drill hole names, Column B holds the measurements. For every entry of a name in column A I want to return the equivalent range in column B. Then feed that range to the median, min and max functions.

Essentially a vlookup that returns a range instead of just a value.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the values in column A are sorted ascending, you can get the range with an Index function.

INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,1))

Fed that to the Min() function like this.

=MIN(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,0)):INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E2,A:A,1)))

See screenshot for the setup. The formula is in cell E3.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much  teyln. So I can join results with the colon!

Comment: Yes. The first Index() function returns the address of the first cell, the second Index() function returns the address of the last cell for the specified name. The colon as an operator will make this into a range, just like =A1:Z20 is a range with a colon between the first and the last cell. Be aware that the list MUST be sorted ascending in Column A for this to work.